# using sed command need to change one line in nginx conf

Tags: sed

Need to change one line in nginx.conf

client_max_body_size 1m to client_max_body_size 10m I used this command

```
sed -i "s/^client_max_body_size 1m;$/client_max_body_size 10m;/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed: 1: "nginx.conf": extra characters at the end of n command
```

got this message... I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
sed -i '' 's/^client_max_body_size 1m;$/client_max_body_size 10m;/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

The `''` after `-i` option in FreeBSD `sed` enable inplace matching.